# Save a record during a ActiveRecord::Rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im working in a complex system and in a certain method there is a possibility of the record is not valid and trigger a ActiveRecord::Rollback.

My problem is: That method needs to update a record either if there is success or if ActiveRecord::Rollback is raised and i cant find how to do that.

Can someone help me to solve that?
Thks,

Answer (score 0):

You can skip validation

```
Model.save(validate: false)
```

[rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations)

Comment: This didnt work because the record i need to update is valid but other actions will trigger ActiveRecord::Rollback and will dismiss the updated record.

Comment: I'm confused. Can we see some codes? And alternatively you can try Model.update_attribute(hello: "world)